# Mysql- Distinct results on comparing two tables fields

Tags: mysql

Hi I have two tables A & B that are connected to each other via id & Aid. Table-A contains name and area of particular person. A person may have two or more addresses and Table-B contains type and stype of persons described in Table-A.

**Table-A**

```
id          name            area

1           Ram             ABCD
2           Ram             XYZZ
3           Ravi            XYZZ
4           Sam             ABCD
```

**Table-B**

```
Aid         type            stype

1           DE              DE-1
2           DE              DE-1
3           AC              AC-1
3           AC              AC-2
3           AC              AC-3
4           DE              DE-1
```

Now to retrieve names i use queries like

```
SELECT name FROM A,B WHERE A.id=B.Aid AND type=DE
```

**Output**:

```
name

Ram
Ram
Sam
```

**Desired Output**:

```
name

Ram
Ram
Sam
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT name FROM A,B WHERE A.id=B.Aid AND type=AC
```

**Output**:

```
name

Ravi
Ravi
Ravi
```

**Desired Output**:

```
name

Ravi
```

Desired outputs are outputs i am looking for. I want to display those duplicate name also who have different area. If i use Group by name it displays Ram or Ravi once. How i can get desired outputs...Thanks in advance....

Comment: You’re aware that you can group by more than one column, right …?

Comment: Didn't use any time yet...

Comment: Group by name, area solved my problem...Thanks...